# How to add grab source's TEXT/MTEXT text height for the other texts to be replaced?

Tags: lisp, autocad, cad, autolisp

I currently have this code modified by gileCAD and I myself tried modifying. But I currently wanted to also grab the source text's text height as well when replacing other text but with the code below, I get an error of "Program ERROR: bad DXF group: 50.0".

```
                    (defun c:MTP (/ cEnt elst text color ss i textSize)
                    (if (and (setq cEnt (car (nentsel "\nSelect Source Text: ")))
                                (member (cdr (assoc 0 (entget cEnt)))
                                    '("TEXT" "MTEXT" "ATTRIB")
                                )
                        1)
                        (progn
                        (setq elst (entget cEnt)
                              text (assoc 1 elst)
                              color (cond ((assoc 62 elst))
                                        (T '(62 . 256))
                                    )
                              textSize (cdr (assoc 40 elst)) ; get text size
                        )
                        (redraw cEnt 3)
                                (if (setq ss (ssget '((0 . "TEXT,MTEXT"))))
                                (repeat (setq i (sslength ss))
                                (setq elst (entget (ssname ss (setq i (1- i)))))
                                    (entmod
                                        (subst text
                                            (assoc 1 elst)
                                                (if (assoc 62 elst)
                                                (entmod (subst color (assoc 62 elst) elst))
                                                (append elst (list color))
                                            )
                                            (entmod (subst textSize (assoc 40 elst) elst))
                                            (append elst (list textSize))
                                        )                   
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    (command "_regenall")
                    (princ)
                )
```

Modified code from CAD Developer: It doesn't have any error and it does use the source text's text height and text color but doesn't replace the select text/mtext that matches the content of the source text.

```
(defun c:MTP (/ cEnt elst text color ss i textSize)
                (if (and (setq cEnt (car (nentsel "\nSelect Source Text: ")))
                            (member (cdr (assoc 0 (entget cEnt)))
                                '("TEXT" "MTEXT" "ATTRIB")
                            )
                    1)
                    (progn
                    (setq elst (entget cEnt)
                          text (assoc 1 elst)
                          color (cond ((assoc 62 elst))
                                    (T '(62 . 256))
                                )
                          textSize (cdr (assoc 40 elst)) ; get text size
                    )
                    (redraw cEnt 3)
                            (if (setq ss (ssget '((0 . "TEXT,MTEXT"))))
                            (repeat (setq i (sslength ss))
                            (setq elst (entget (ssname ss (setq i (1- i)))))
                                (entmod
                                   (subst text
                                      (assoc 1 elst)
                                      (if (assoc 62 elst)
                                        (entmod (subst color (assoc 62 elst) elst))
                                        (append elst (list color))
                                      )
                                   )
                                )
                                (entmod 
                                   (if (assoc 40 elst)
                                      (subst (cons 40 textSize) (assoc 40 elst) elst)
                                      (append elst (list (cons 40 textSize)))
                                   )                                            
                                )                                   
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                (command "_regenall")
                (princ)
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text height is code 40

```
(defun c:MTP (/ cEnt elst text color ss i textSize)
    (if (and (setq cEnt (car (nentsel "\nSelect Source Text: ")))
                (member (cdr (assoc 0 (entget cEnt)))
                    '("TEXT" "MTEXT" "ATTRIB")
                )
        1)
        (progn
        (setq elst (entget cEnt)
              text (cdr(assoc 1 elst))
              color (if (assoc 62 elst)
                        (cdr (assoc 62 elst) )
                         256
                    )
              textSize (cdr (assoc 40 elst))  ; get text size
        )
        (redraw cEnt 3)
                (if (setq ss (ssget '((0 . "TEXT,MTEXT"))))
                (repeat (setq i (sslength ss))
                (setq DXEntity(ssname ss (setq i (1- i))) )
                (DXF:Put DXEntity 1 text)
                (DXF:Put DXEntity 40 textSize)
                (DXF:Put DXEntity 62 color)
                )
            )
        )
    )
    (command "_regenall")
    (princ)
)
( defun DXF:Put( DXEntity code newValue / elst )    ; (setq code 1) (setq newValue "test")
    (setq elst (entget DXEntity))
    (entmod 
        (if (assoc code elst)
            (subst (cons code newValue) (assoc code elst) elst)
            (append elst (list (cons code newValue)))
        )                                            
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I somewhat knew it was my placing of the entmod for assoc 40 that is misplaced. Thank you once again, sir.

Comment: Sorry but I now it doesn't change the text to be replaced. It does follow the color as well as text height but the text from the source text would not replace the other text :(

Comment: So  let's put it all together

Comment: Thank you so much! That now works as intended, I thank you once again.